# How to resolve environment variables in runtime in java

Tags: java, environment-variables

My java application needs to resolve environment variables in file paths at runtime , file paths will be specified in properties file as below
in case of windows it will be %JAVA_HOME%\certs\myselffign.cer
in case of unix it will be $JAVA_HOME\certs\myselffign.cer

My java apps needs to resolve those file path to absolute paths and load the certificates into truststore.

Is there any way to this.
As of now i am checking os.name , and if os.name is windows then pattern matching for %% and using system.getenv , in case of non windows looking for $.

I am hoping there is a better way to do this

Comment: `System.getEnv()` *is* how you do it.  What's your question?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the standard (Java) template syntax of ${java.home} in your property files, then replace it at Runtime with the value of `System.getProperty("java.home");`. So in your file instead of:

```
certificate=%JAVA_HOME%\certs\myselffign.cer (Windows)
certificate=$JAVA_HOME\certs\myselffign.cer (*nix)
```

Just use a standard:

```
certificate=${java.home}/certs/myselfsign.cer
```

And in code do something like:

```
String javaHomePath = System.getProperty("java.home")l
Properties props = Properties.load( ...);
String certFilePath = props.get("certificate");
certFilePath = certFilePath.replaceAll("${java.home}", javaHomePath);
```

Mind you, using the standard template syntax also allows you to use some of the open source property replacement tools out there. Like Spring PropertyResolver. Hope that helps.